# TypeScript check if variable is a tuple or array of tuples

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, narrowing

Given the following code for example purposes only:

```js
type tuple = [key: string, value: number];

function foo(arg: tuple | Array<tuple>) {
  const arr = Array.isArray(arg[0]) ? arg : [arg];
  // The type of arr is: tuple | (tuple | tuple[])[]
  console.log(arr.length);
}

foo(['key', 111]);
foo([['key', 222]]);
```

I've also tried `typeof arg[0] === 'string' ? [arg] : arg` but that also results in the same result.  Running the code has the expected outcome, that `arr` is always an array of tuples, but TypeScript doesn't "know" it.

How can I get typescript to correctly narrow the type of `arr` to be `tuple[]` without asserting it explicitly?

Comment: Shouldn't it be isArray(arg)?

Comment: `isArray(arg)` would always be true, since a tuple itself is an array.  I need to test the first element, given the two possibilities, to see if I can get TypeScript to discern between the two.  But it appears it doesn't work that way.  Still not sure why, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler only sees that you're assigning either `arg` or `[arg]` to `arr`. It doesn't change what it thinks the type of `arg` is based on `Array.isArray(arg[0])`, so `arr`'s type is the union of the types of `arg` and `[arg]`. The type of `arg` is `tuple | tuple[]` so the type of `[arg]` is `(tuple | tuple[])[]`; the union of those types simplifies to `tuple | (tuple | tuple[])[]` since `tuple[]` is a subset of `(tuple | tuple[])[]`.

You can wrap `Array.isArray` in a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to have the compiler interpret things the way you want.

```
function isArrayOfTuples(arg: tuple | tuple[]): arg is tuple[] {
    return Array.isArray(arg[0]);
}

function foo(arg: tuple | tuple[]) {
    const arr: tuple[] = isArrayOfTuples(arg) ? arg : [arg];
    console.log(arr.length);
}
```

Otherwise I think you will have to assert the types explicitly to do this.

```
const arr: tuple[] = Array.isArray(arg[0]) ? arg as tuple[] : [arg] as tuple[];
```

Another option which may be simpler to implement in general is to change the type of `arg` to just `tuple[]`. Callers who want to pass a single `tuple` can wrap the argument in an array.

Comment: I understood why `tuple | (tuple | tuple[])[]` was the resulting type, I just wanted to know if it was maybe a bug that TypeScript couldn't figure it out.  There are only two possible types `arg` could be.  If `arg[0]` is a string or `arg[0]` is an Array, that completely narrows it down, as far as I can tell.

I will say, the user-defined type guard is an option I had forgotten about!

That approach does work.